# Not able to pass the value in codemirror component to the useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, text-editor, codemirror

so im trying to send the value from the textfield of codemirror component to the parent component usestate called setendpoint where in that endpoint i have values like {url = "", headers = {}, params = {}, body = "" } . I passed the endpoint component to the  Reqbodyinput.jsx component where there is different child components like header, parameter, and  body . then I have passed props to the body for setting the values that changes from the body to the hook in the app or the parent component . now when is set the values that changed in codemirror component to setendpoint{body: value} the codemirror textfield become disable and I am not able to write in the field. I have tried many methods but none of the methods work

I use codemirror package and its lang extensions and for different langs support in the text field. If anyone have any solution it will be very helpful for me.

```
import CodeMirror from "@uiw/react-codemirror";
import { dracula } from "@uiw/codemirror-theme-dracula";
import { json } from "@codemirror/lang-json";
import { javascript } from "@codemirror/lang-javascript";
import { xml } from "@codemirror/lang-xml";
import { html } from "@codemirror/lang-html";
```

if I set the value with usestate inside the same component called textformat it works fine but it is no use for me because I want to pass it to the parent component for making an api request.

```
// Body Component
function Body({ setEndpoint, endpoint }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("JSON");

  function TextFormat() {

    // I want to pass the value to setEndpoint({ ...endpoint, body: newValue }) but it is not working. help ME !!

    const handleChange = React.useCallback((value, viewUpdate) => {
      console.log('value:', value);
      setEndpoint({ ...endpoint, body: value })
    }, []);



    return (
      <Col md={12}>
        <CodeMirror
          theme={dracula}
          height="25vh"
          extensions={
            value === "JSON"
              ? [json()]
              : value === "JavaScript"
              ? [javascript()]
              : value === "HTML"
              ? [html()]
              : [xml()]
          }
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </Col>
    );
  }

  function handleDropDownValue(event) {
    setValue(event.target.textContent);
  }

  return (
    <div className="px-4 parameter-area">
      <Row className="">
        <Col md={1} className="w-auto">
          <p>Content Type</p>
        </Col>
        <Col md={1}>
          <Dropdown>
            <Dropdown.Toggle
              variant="plain"
              className="custom-dropdown-toggle"
              style={{ fontSize: "1rem", padding: "0" }}
            >
              {value}
            </Dropdown.Toggle>
            <Dropdown.Menu variant="dark">
              <Dropdown.Item onClick={handleDropDownValue}>Text</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item onClick={handleDropDownValue}>JSON</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Divider
                style={{ backgroundColor: "grey" }}
              ></Dropdown.Divider>
              <Dropdown.Item onClick={handleDropDownValue}>
                JavaScript
              </Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item onClick={handleDropDownValue}>HTML</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item onClick={handleDropDownValue}>XML</Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
          </Dropdown>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row className="g-2">
        <TextFormat />
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried useeffect to update the hook but still it make more errors in the console. also tried other hooks to but still didn't work.